# Sort mixed text lines (alphanum) in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have txt file with every line structure like this:

```
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(212)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171666)**seqNo:U(81920)**]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(184)updateVersion:U(3)checksum:U(748981000)
```

And have to sort file lines based on seqNo (min to max). Sequence number can be virtually any number starting from zero. Any idea how can it be done in efficient way?

Comment: If that is *one line* of your input file then we can't possibly help you to sort it: it is already sorted! Please take a look at [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [*Markdown Editing Help*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You should provide much more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Schwartzian Transform* as suggested in [Toto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39548832/5830574) is probably the fastest way to sort your lines here. But you said you're a Perl newbie, and I like to show how the lines can be sorted *traditionally*.

Perl has a [`sort` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) that sorts a list simply by alphabet. But you can supply a custom comparison function and let `sort` use *your* function to compare the elements. During its operation `sort` must continuously compare two elements (=lines) of your list and decide which one is greater or lesser or whether they are equal.

If you supply a comparison function, `sort` will call it with two such elements as the parameters `$a` and `$b`. You <strike>do not need to</strike> must not declare `$a` and `$b`, they are magic and just there. Your comparison function could look like this:

```
sub by_seqNo
{
    # extract the sequence number from $a and $b
    my ($seqA) = ($a =~ /seqNo:U\((\d+)/);
    my ($seqB) = ($b =~ /seqNo:U\((\d+)/);

    # numerically compare the sequence numbers (returns -1/0/+1)
    $seqA <=> $seqB;
}
```

The first two lines extract the numbers after `seqNo:U(` and store them as `$seqA` and `$seqB`. The third line compares these sequence numbers as integers and returns that result. Combined with the `sort` function this gives:

```
my @sorted = sort by_seqNo @lines;
```

The reason why the *Schwartzian Transform (ST)* is faster than this solution is because the ST does the (expensive) operation of extracting the seqNo from your lines exactly once for each line. The "traditional" approach on the other hand extracts the seqNo twice for each comparison.

Comment: Thanks  for the explanation. It is really  nice to be able to learn with you guys here. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Here is a small script that does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fhi, '<', 'path/to/input/file' or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
my @lines = <$fhi>;
my @sorted = map { $_->[0] }
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map { my ($x) = $_ =~ /SeqNo:U\((\d+)/i; [$_, $x]; }
             @lines;
open my $fho, '>', 'path/to/output/file' or die "Unable to open output file: $!";
print $fho $_ for @sorted;
```

Comment: Thanks, could you write it as a stand alone script, since I am newbie in perl