# Use Schwartzian transform across multiple files

Tags: perl, sorting

I would like to use the following Schwartzian transform sorting script (which is working perfectly as a standalone script), on a multiple files in the folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $input, '<', '/home/test/file1' or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
my @file = <$input>;
my @sorted_file = map { $_->[0] }
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map { my ($x) = $_ =~ /VerNumber:\((\d+)/i; [$_, $x]; }
             @file;
open my $output, '>', '/home/test/sorted/file1' or die "Unable to open output file: $!";
print $output $_ for @sorted_file;
```

The script should take as an input all the files in one folder starting with file*, and sort the content of each one:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
...
file1000.txt
```

Then, as an output I would like for the script to create new folder in which it will place new files, with the sorted content, keeping the same file names.

```
/sorted
file1.txt -> /sorted/file1.txt
file2.txt -> /sorted/file2.txt
...
file1000.txt -> /sorted/file1000.txt
```

Any ideas how this can be done efficently? I have almost 1000 files, each one containing about 3000 arrays which are being sorted with the mentioned script.

I have made an attempt. The following script does write the files in the output folder, keeping the same file names, but the sorting part is not working (even though the standalone script is sorting the files). I am getting the same files in the ouput.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $version="0.2";
my $files_match="";
my $files_dir="";
my $file_name="";
my $help_flag="";
my $version_flag="";

GetOptions(
           'm|match=s' => \$files_match,
           'd|directory=s' => \$files_dir,
           'h|help' => \$help_flag, 'v|version' => \$version_flag,
);

sub sorting {
my @file = "$_";
my @sorted = map { $_->[0] }
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map { my ($x) = $_ =~ /VerNumber:\((\d+)/i; [$_, $x]; }
             @file;
print FILE $_;
}

if (($files_match ne "") and ($files_dir ne "")) {
        chdir("$files_dir") or die "$!";
        opendir (DIR, ".") or die "$!";
        my @files = grep {/$files_match/} readdir DIR;
        my $files_size = $#files + 1;
        my $index_file = 1;
        print "Files to process: $files_size\n";
        close DIR;

        foreach (@files) {
                open(FILE, ">./sorted/$_.sort") or die $!;
                my @singlefile = $_;
                print "Processing $index_file of $files_size files: $_\n";
                local @ARGV = @singlefile;
                while(<>){
                       sorting($_);
                }    
                close(FILE);
                $index_file++;
                print "OK: Sorted @singlefile \n";
        }
    } elsif ((!$help_flag) and (!$version_flag)){printHelp();}
```

I am a beginner in Perl and any help would be more than welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We will happily help you if you have made an attempt at writing a solution but can't get it to work. You will remain a beginner forever if you don't *try something*.

Comment: Your line `open my $output, '>' or die "Unable to open output file: $!"` is wrong. You haven't provided a filename.

Comment: Same for `open my $input, '<' or ...` -- missing filename.  Create a directory with `make_path` from core module [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html).  Get the list of files to process with, for example, [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).  Then iterate over that list doing mostly what you are.  Let us know if there are problems with it.

Comment: FWIW: the ST code comes from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39548832/5830574).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comments. I have edited my question and corrected the mistake you stated regarding the missing file name in the  "open my $input, '<' or ..." and "open my $output, '<' or ..." line. 

@Borodin, thank you for your comment. I have tried to write a solution (I edited my question and place it there) . With this scirpt I can get the desired form of reading/writing the files but the problem is that as a result I am getting the same content of the files, instead of a sorted one. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Sonya Your `sub sorting` is _not correct_ -- very basic things are wrong with it.  I'd suggest that you read up on subroutines in Perl, you can get up to speed with basics _very_ quickly, which is all you need for this purpose. Also, it is easier to transfer all your sorting work to the sub -- just pass in input and output file names, much like in the answer by [`Dave Cross`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross).  Also, when you print, do not use a global `FILE`, there are all kinds of issues you'll run into -- you want a lexical `my $fh` instead.

Comment: @Sonya  Your `foreach (@files)` loop relies on advanced tricks. But the actual problem is that the call `sorting($_)` passes a single line of each file to the "sorting" subroutine. (In which you take a scalar value, `"$_"`, to sort.)  It will be far easier to put _all_ sorting code in a subroutine and to use very simple and basic processing of the file list.

Answer (score 1):

You have code to sort one file. Put that code into a subroutine. Call it `sort_one_file()`.

```
sub sort_one_file {
  # You have this code already
}
```

That's not quite right though. You need to define the `$input` and `$output` variables. Let's assume that we're going to pass them into the subroutine.

```
sub sort_one_file {
  my ($input, $output) = @_;

  # You already have this code
}
```

Ok. So how do we call this function. That's easy.

```
sort_one_file($input, $output);
```

You don't show us the code that populates `$input` and `$output` in your original program, but if you add that back, then this will work the same way as your current program.

But now we want to call our subroutine many times. Let's make it easy for ourselves and assume that we pass the list of input files as command line arguments to our program. That makes our program as flexible as possible.

```
foreach my $input (@ARGV) {
  sort_one_file($input, $output);
}
```

We're almost there, but we have one small problem. We can get `$input` from `@ARGV`, but what about `$output`? Well, I don't know what rules you're using to rename the files. So let's make some assumptions and hide them away in another subroutine.

```
sub get_output_name {
  my ($input) = @_;

  # Change this to whatever renaming rule you are using.
  return "$input.new";
}
```

We can then use that inside our loop.

```
foreach my $input (@ARGV) {
  sort_one_file($input, get_output_name($input));
}
```

There are other approaches. I might just use `<>` so that I don't need to bother with opening the input files (and then I'd need to keep track of what's in `$ARGV` in order to know when I start to process a new file). But this is pretty simple and will work.

**Update:** As others have pointed out in comments, your existing code to open a file is incorrect. You have:

```
open my $input, '<' or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
```

This doesn't include the name of the file to open. I think you want this:

```
open my $input_fh, '<', $input
  or die "Unable to open input file: $input - $!";
```

You'll also need to change the next line to:

```
my @file = <$input_fh>;
```

There's the same problem with your output `open()`.

But actually, that `@file` array is completely unnecessary. I'd write that as:

```
open my $input_fh,  '<', $input
  or die "Unable to open input file: $input - $!";
open my $output_fh, '>', $output
  or die "Unable to open output file: $output - $!";

print $output_fh map { $_->[0] }
                 sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
                 map { my ($x) = $_ =~ /VerNumber:\((\d+)/i; [$_, $x]; }
                 <$input_fh>;
```